# Git Command Cycle for Central Repo With Multiple Developers

Tags: git

One way to collaborate using `git` is for each developer to hold their own branch ([suggested by Git here](https://about.gitlab.com/topics/version-control/what-is-git-workflow/)). This is only advised for small teams.

**The workflow is as follows:**

- Each developer has their own branch, which they work on across their various computers / locations (so they developer's branches must be pushed to remote)
- When a unit of work is done, they merge their own branch with a branch called `dev`
- `dev` is merged with `master` when `dev` is ready for production

**Illustration of the above workflow, with two developers:**

[image]

**I (*developer 1*) thought of the following command cycle, starting at the `Developer-1` branch (purposefully avoiding `git pull`):**

```
 1. $ (Developer-1) git fetch --all
 2. $ (Developer-1) git merge origin/Developer-1
 3. $ (Developer-1) git merge origin/dev
 4. Do some work on `Developer-1` over time, during which it is likely that other devs push to remote
 5. $ (Developer-1) git fetch --all
 6. $ (Developer-1) git merge origin/Developer-1
 7. $ (Developer-1) git merge origin/dev
 8. $ (Developer-1) git push Developer-1:Developer-1
 9. $ (Developer-1) git push Developer-1:dev
10. Restart cycle from (1)
```

Here is a shorter version, using `git pull` and git's built-in name resolution (in case helpful to someone else):

```
 1. $ (Developer-1) git pull
 2. $ (Developer-1) git merge origin/dev
 3. Do some work on `Developer-1` over time, during which it is likely that other devs push to remote
 4. $ (Developer-1) git pull
 5. $ (Developer-1) git merge origin/dev
 6. $ (Developer-1) git push Developer-1:Developer-1
 7. $ (Developer-1) git push Developer-1:dev
 8. Restart cycle from (1)
```

When I want to test the `dev` branch:

```
 1. $ (Developer-1) git switch dev
 2. $ (dev) git fetch --all
 3. $ (dev) git merge origin/dev
```

When I want to push to production:

```
 1. $ (dev) git switch master
 2. $ (master) git fetch --all
 3. $ (master) git merge origin/dev
 2. $ (master) git push master:master
```

**Resources**

1. [Workflow 4 here](https://about.gitlab.com/topics/version-control/what-is-git-workflow/#:%7E:text=A%20centralized%20Git%20workflow%20enables,without%20using%20any%20other%20branch.), is the same as above
2. [The Distributed Workflows](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows) chapter from the git book are also illustrating a centralized workflow, but not exactly the approach above

**Questions**

1. Is my command cycles the right way to implement the above workflow?
2. Is the above workflow a common way to collaborate, when you have a small team with a centralized repo?

Comment: Please stop treating git like SVN. Don’t give branches to a singular developer. This approach will cause you problems. — 1) no, it’s not common, because centralised workflows go against the design of how git works. 2) there is no “right one”. The branching strategy seems similar to “feature branches”. Try using that instead?

Comment: @evolutionxbox A centralized workflow is actually suggested by git itself: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows. Perhaps it is better for all developers to just work directly on 'dev', however then my code would be polluted by lots of unfinished code others are working on... That does not work.. Your suggestion is basically to only use a branch for one specific task, then delete it after? So that one branch does not persist over time (well, dev would)?

Comment: Ok so I’ve learnt I shouldn’t be so dogmatic with centralised workflows

Comment: Your diagram is quite misleading: it suggests the three top-row commits are only on branch `Developer-1` for instance. But they are all *on* `master` at this point; in fact, given the way the drawing goes, *every* visible commit is on `master`. Draw the branch names on the right, pointing to the last commit; the commits that are "on" that branch are all those you can find by working backwards along the arrows, including any on any other branches that you find by this process.

Comment: If you're used to, well, just about any other version control system, the idea that one commit could be on two or more branches simultaneously could be shocking. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm cranky today, which perhaps enables me to take the cynical point of view that the first [4 described GitLab workflows](https://about.gitlab.com/topics/version-control/what-is-git-workflow/) are all effectively the same.

1. > A centralized workflow involves every contributor committing to the main branch without using any other branch.

   My local branch is called `main`.
2. > Rather than commit directly to the main branch, developers create a branch, make changes, and then merge it into main.

   My local branch is named `feat/my-feature`.
3. > Trunk-based development facilitates concurrent development on a single branch called trunk.

   My local branch is named `trunk`. For simplicity let's just call it `main` instead and then this obviously becomes #1.
4. > Personal branching is similar to feature branching, but rather than have a single branch per feature, it’s per developer.

   My local branch is called `user/TTT/my-feature`.

So, effectively, the *only* difference in these workflows is what you call your local branch. The way you update your local branch with the latest version of the remote `main`, and also how you push, **can be the same regardless of workflow**!

For example, regardless of which workflow you're using above, to update your local branch with the upstream `main`, you could:

```
# if you prefer rebase (my personal preference most of the time)
git pull --rebase origin main
# or
git fetch
git rebase origin/main

# if you prefer merge
git pull origin main
# or
git fetch
git merge origin/main
```

And when it's time to push:

```
# No code review
git push origin <local-branch-name>:main

# Using a code review
git push origin <local-branch-name> # and then create a PR/MR into main
```

**Notes:**

1. It's possible to use a shorter version of some of these commands based on if your local branch is tracking the remote. For example, if you aren't using code reviews, then your local feature branch might be setup to track `origin/main`, in which case `git pull` and `git push` can be used without specifying other branch names. If you are using code reviews you typically would prefer to track upstream branches of the same name as the local branch, to avoid confusion.
2. Branches are just pointers to a commit. You could change to any of these 4 workflows anytime you want simply by renaming your local branch.
3. The difference between multiple feature branches (#2) and a single personal branch name (#4) is a pointless distinction. If you're working on only one thing at a time, and you always use the same branch name, it doesn't matter if you call it a feature branch or a personal branch. If you're working on more than one thing at a time, it doesn't matter if you have multiple feature branches or multiple personal branches, or multiple stashes, or multiple saved copies of your work outside of your repo, in the respect that doing so changes the name of the workflow you're using.

**Conclusion:** all of these workflows are basically the same, and your suggested workflow is a common way to collaborate without code reviews on the remote side. (Maybe you're pair programming or just don't need the code reviews.) As for your addition of a second shared branch so you have both `dev` and `master` branches, that's fairly common as well, if you wish to track historical releases which are indicated by merging `dev` into `master`. Though, some don't bother with the `master` branch in your case and would just tag the commit on `dev` that is released to production, when it happens. It's essentially the same thing. I personally like having a branch indicating what's in production so it's easier to make a hotfix from `master`, instead of from "the most recent release tag on `dev`".

**Side Note:** at my company, we used to name all of our branches, `feat/12345-my-cool-feature` (sounds like workflow #2) but later moved to `user/first.name/12345-my-cool-feature` (sounds like workflow #4). (We don't impose a restriction on how many branches you can make.) The reason we asked people to use their name when creating a branch is simply so when we look at remote branches we have an idea of who created them and/or who to talk to when they become stale. (Especially useful when someone leaves the company.) It also has the added benefit that we all know any branch prefixed with `user/*` can and will be rewritten, and shouldn't be the base for new branches unless you are comfortable using `rebase --onto` when the branch gets rewritten.

Comment: Really helpful post, thank you @TTT. Unless I am mistaken, it might be smart to push ones local branch to remote, if working across different computers. If so, I cannot setup .git/config as you suggest (the fetch and merge fields). I have to follow the stream of commands I posted in the OP, right?

Comment: @Magnus working on multiple machines shouldn't necessitate any config changes. And in workflows 1 and 3 each of your machines would act like another user. For workflows #2 and #4 specifically, if you are working on the same feature in two places, push to your named branch when you finish your session, and pull from that same branch when you resume from the other machine. When you pull, I'd probably use `git pull --rebase`, in case you forget to do this when you start and already made new commits on the other machine.

Comment: Apologies, I think I was a bit unclear. In your *note 1* I understood that you suggested that we set the upstream of our local branch with an arbitrary name, let's call it `X`, to the remote `dev` branch, in order to push and pull without having to specify the remote branch name explicitly (this is done by modifying the `.git/config` file, either directly or indirectly via a command). However, if I want to push/pull both `X` <-> `X`, and `X` <-> `dev` from time to time, I have to follow my original recipe, right?

Comment: @Magnus Note you can always pull from and push to any branch just by specifying it when you run the command. Setting the upstream is a convenience so you don't have to specify the remote branch name each time. (And has a small additional benefit that having an upstream provides a little more info when you use `git status`.) So, in the case where you want to push the branch name instead of the shared branch, I'd just set the upstream to that named branch since you'll push and pull from that most often. If you ever want to pull from or push to the shared branch, specify its name in the command.

Comment: @Magnus And yes, it looks like what you proposed is pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

If you search the web for "git workflow", you will find dozens, or probably hundreds, of articles discussing particular workflows, their pros and cons, and details of how to implement them.

There is one common piece of advice, though: **in git, branches are cheap**: most workflows involve creating and deleting several branches a week, maybe several a day. The actual history mechanisms in git are all based around *commits*, with branches just as convenient, and mostly temporary, labels.

If you limit yourself to one branch per developer, you can't leave a branch unmerged while it is tested or code reviewed, or pause work to work on something higher priority; and you can't take over someone else's task if they're off sick or on leave. That's why you'll generally see workflows using branches to represent individual units of work.

There may be some advantage to treating those branches as "owned by" a particular developer, so that they are free to rewrite history (amend commits, rebase onto a new starting point, etc).

The other thing that's unusual in your proposed workflow (although not strictly "wrong", since it will result in a usable history) is that you push the developer branch directly to "dev". It would be more common to switch to "dev", merge the developer (or task) branch into that, and then push the result.

The other thing I advise you to read up on are the advantages of central tools like Gitlab, Bitbucket, Github, or Gerrit, which facilitate and enforce peer review of code, rather than letting all users push directly to the main long-running branches. The merge into "dev" then happens on the server, controlled by the review tool, and developers only need to work on their own branches.

Comment: Do not vote to close and also answer the question.

Comment: @matt Yeah, I changed my mind and meant to retract my vote. Too late now :/

Comment: Can we open it again, please? This is very helpful. I voted to reopen.

Comment: I think the question still balances on being highly opinionated

Comment: Potentially, but I have no doubt it would be helpful to other developers knowing whether the structure of the git commands I posted is right. For instance, it might be incorrect to push from one branch locally to another on the remote. Maybe I should instead checkout dev and merge it, then push it. Things like that are typically not answered on websites presenting different workflows (they usually leave out the actual commands). Thanks to those that voted!

Comment: @IMSoP If/when you have a moment, it would be super helpful if you could have a quick a look at the commands I posted and see if that is the right way to implement the workflow.

Comment: Side-note: I modified the question to not be an opinion question, but rather an implementation question.

Comment: @Magnus Whether something is "the right way" is very much going to be a matter of opinion, but I have added a little bit to the answer.

Comment: @IMSoP Not too late. :) Perfectly fine now.

Comment: @IMSoP thanks, good to know that it is more common to swap branches, merge, then push. I will see if there are ways to make it a bit more streamlined. Feels messy having to jump back and forth and merge both ways to keep two branches in sync. Ideally, I would have preferred to do the following in just three commands: D-1 is merged with remote (git pull from D-1), dev is merged with remote (git pull from dev), D-1 is merged into dev (git merge D-1 from dev), dev is merged into D-1 (git merge dev from D-1). Is there a shortcut for the latter two operations (i.e. merge then FF D-1 branch)?

Comment: It is actually a bit surprising to me that the branch pointer being merged in is not moved after merge. Is there a flag or something to force that to happen? I.e. $ (dev) git merge D-1, I would love for D-1 to be fast-forwarded to the new merge commit, after the merge.

Comment: @Magnus: the reason the *other* branch pointer is not moved is because a branch name means *this is the last commit that we should consider to be "on" the branch*. The commits you merged in are now on *both* branches, but the new *merge commit* is only "on" the branch you're on. If you want the new merge commit to be on the other branch too, you must merge it there. If you disable fast-forward merging, this makes a new merge commit that's *only* on `D-1`.

Comment: In any case, this is why we tend to delete a branch name after merging: once the commits are on both branches, we don't need the *name* to pick out the last commit of some feature. We find it by looking backwards on the integration path.

Comment: @torek Great points. Instead of merging it back again, I actually just moved it. Is it better to just merge it back again? See my answer below.

Comment: `git merge --ff-only` (which says "move only if this is a fast-forward op") adds a bit of checking, but otherwise it's the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a more git-like implementation of the workflow in question. It does not push from one local branch to a remote branch with a different name.

Hope it is helpful to someone else as well.

```
 1. $ (Developer-1) git pull #merge in remote changes to current branch (in case developer moved between computers). Most likely FF merge.
 2. Do some work on `Developer-1` branch over time, during which it is likely that other devs push to remote
 3. $ (Developer-1) git push
 4. $ (Developer-1) git switch dev
 5. $ (dev) git pull #merge in remote changes to current branch.
 6. $ (dev) git merge Developer-1 #merge in local branch Developer-1 into local branch dev.
 7. $ (dev) git push #push the newly updated dev branch to remote
 8. $ (dev) git branch -f Developer-1 #move local Developer-1 branch pointer from the pre-merge commit, to wherever dev now points to (which will be a new merge commit if a "true merge" happened).
 9. $ (dev) git switch Developer-1
10. $ (Developer-1) git push
11. Restart from 1
```

**Results**

- Developer-1 is updated and pushed to remote
- dev receives changes from Developer-1
- dev is pushed to remote
- Developer-1 pointer is moved to dev. This is an important step, to make this workflow function correctly. Since Developer-1 was merged into dev, moving the Developer-1 pointer will not result in any conflict with Developer-1 on the remote server. It will simply be ahead of its remote version, so the remote version is updated next time you push Developer-1.
- In other words, if you accidentally try to pull from Developer-1 on remote to Developer-1 locally, after moving the pointer, you will just be told that Developer-1 is up to date. Again, because the remote version is now an ancestor of your local copy, in the commit chain.
- It is also good to know that git will not allow you to push anything to remote, if you have not first merged changes from remote into the local branch. So, you don't have to worry about forgetting one of the pull commands above, before pushing. Git will keep you in line and avoid errors.

**Alternative**

As @torek pointed out in the comments to the other answer, merging with ff-only is the same as just moving the pointer. So this works too:

```
 1. $ (Developer-1) git pull #merge in remote changes to current branch (in case developer moved between computers). Most likely FF merge.
 2. Do some work on `Developer-1` branch over time, during which it is likely that other devs push to remote
 3. $ (Developer-1) git push
 4. $ (Developer-1) git switch dev
 5. $ (dev) git pull #merge in remote changes to current branch.
 6. $ (dev) git merge Developer-1 #merge in local branch Developer-1 into local branch dev.
 7. $ (dev) git push #push the newly updated dev branch to remote
 8. $ (dev) git switch Developer-1
 9. $ (Developer-1) git merge dev --ff-only #merge dev branch back into Developer-1 branch, via ff-only (flag should not be needed, but just in case)
10. $ (Developer-1) git push
11. Restart from 1
```